# Stray\342 inprogram

Tags: arduino-uno

What does this mean?? Stray\342 inprogram

```
// Basic sketch for EmonWRT
// Version 1.2

#define FILTERSETTLETIME 15000 // Time (ms) to allow the filters to settle before sending data

const int CT1 = 1;
const int CT2 = 1; // Set to 0 to disable CT channel 2
const int CT3 = 1; // Set to 0 to disable CT channel 3
const int VOLT = 1; // Set to 0 to disable

const int UNO = 1; // Set to 0 if your not using the UNO bootloader (i.e using Duemilanove) – All Atmega’s shipped from OpenEnergyMonitor come with Arduino Uno bootloader
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <JeeLib.h> // Download JeeLib: http://github.com/jcw/jeelib
ISR(WDT_vect) { Sleepy::watchdogEvent(); } // Attached JeeLib sleep function to Atmega328 watchdog -enables MCU to be put into sleep mode inbetween readings to reduce power consumption
#include <EmonLib.h>
EnergyMonitor ct1,ct2,ct3; // Create instances for each CT channel
float power1, power2, power3;
float voltage;
const int LEDpin = 9; // On-board emonTx LED

boolean settled = false;
boolean firstsensor = true; // Just to know if a , must be added in the CSV output

void setup()
{
delay(10000);

Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println(“emonWRT CT123 and Voltage v1.2”);
pinMode(LEDpin, OUTPUT); // Setup indicator LED
digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH);

if (UNO) wdt_enable(WDTO_8S); // Enable anti crash (restart) watchdog if UNO bootloader is selected. Watchdog does not work with duemilanove bootloader // Restarts emonTx if sketch hangs for more than 8s
ct1.voltage(3, 225, 1); // Voltage: input pin, calibration, phase_shift

}

void loop()
{

power1 = ct1.Irms; //ct.calcIrms(number of wavelengths sample)*AC RMS voltage
power2 = ct2.Irms;
power3 = ct3.Irms;
voltage = ct1.Vrms; // AC Mains rms voltage

// because millis() returns to zero after 50 days !
if (!settled && millis() > FILTERSETTLETIME) settled = true;

if (settled) // send data only after filters have settled
{
digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH); delay(2); digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW); // flash LED
**Serial.println(“EMONWRT “);**

if (CT1) {
if (!firstsensor) Serial.println(" ");
firstsensor = false;
Serial.print(power1);
}

if (CT2) {
if (!firstsensor) Serial.println(" ,");
firstsensor = false;
Serial.print(power2);
}

if (CT3) {
if (!firstsensor) Serial.println(",");
firstsensor = false;
Serial.print(power3);
}

if (VOLT) {
if (!firstsensor) Serial.println(" ");
firstsensor = false;
Serial.print(voltage);
}

firstsensor = true;

//Serial.println(” “);
Serial.println(" ");

delay(100);

Sleepy::loseSomeTime(5000); // sleep or delay in seconds – see emontx_lib
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typographic quotes (**“** and **”**) are not part of C/C++ language for defining string literals.

For that you must use straight quotes (i.e. **"**).

Hence replace:

```
Serial.println(“EMONWRT “);
```

with:

```
Serial.println("EMONWRT ");
```

Typographical quotes might get automatically created when using a word processor (e.g. MS Word) to type your source code, or when copying code from a Word document into the Arduino IDE.

The best is to keep away from word processors when typing source code.

Comment: Indeed, this can be a very nasty and subtle issue with modern computers and tools - and it's not just word processors, for example, I had some of these sneak in when some command line instructions where copy and pasted though a collaboration chat tool.